# FullPage JS scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

The website is working as intended so apart from an annoying issue where it automatically scrolls everything back to the start of the second section.

Is there any way I can keep the scroll from the first video background section to the second section and have the second scroll like a normal website without the page scrolling to the top every time I scroll down?

The site can be seen here: http://lukedaly.ninja/gianttest/

This is the plugin I am using: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

All help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: add some more code here. Probably your `css` or if you have any scrolling `jquery`

Comment: I am using the FullPage.js plugin found here: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js 

My CSS can also be seen here:
http://pastebin.com/i0Yk37R8

Been trying to fix this annoying little issue for hours..